# An exponential/polynomial inequality

Tags: inequality, derivatives, exponential-function

Prove that there is at least $1$ real number $a>0$ with the property
$$a^x\ge x^a $$
for any $x>0$.

Comment: What have you tried on this problem? What thoughts do you have? We're not in the habit of just giving out answers without some effort shown.

Comment: Well, I think this is true for a=3, but I am not sure...

Comment: If you have a guess, try graphing it in wolfram alpha.  a=3, does not work, by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it this way:

Let $f(x)=\dfrac{x}{\log x}$ for some $x>0$. Hence, $f^\prime(x)=\dfrac{\log x-1}{\log^2 x}$. I can conclude that $f(x)\geq e$ $\forall\, x>0$.

Therefore, $$f(x)=\dfrac{x}{\log x}\geq e,$$
so, $$x\geq \log x^e,$$
hence, $$e^x\geq x^e.$$

Finally, $\exists a\,>0$ where $a=e$ and $a^x\geq x^a$

Comment: @xyz $f'(x)>0$ only when $x>e$. Note that for $x=0$ we have $f(0)=0 < e$, and since $f$ is continuous it is still under $e$ for any $x$ near zero.

Comment: @Joel Thanks but $x>0$ in the question.

Comment: The problem is a bit deeper than that. Logically you can't solve this by this method.  You have a pole at $x=1$ near which there are values of the function $x/\ln(x)$ that are negative.

Comment: The problem arose when you divide by $\ln(x)$ and $\ln(a)$ after an application of the logarithm: $$a \ln(x) \ge x \ln(a).$$  You can divide by $a$ and $x$ but not $\ln(a)$ or $\ln(x)$.

Comment: You can graph the function $x/\ln(x)$ and see for yourself that there are positive $x$ values where this function is less than $e$.

Answer (score 0):

xyz's method has the right idea. If you consider the equation $$a^x \ge x^a$$ we can rewrite this as the equivalent $$\ln(a)/a \ge \ln(x)/x$$ by using the properities of the logarithm and the positivity of $x$ and $a$.

Thus if you find the $x$ that maximizes $\ln(x)/x$, that is the $a$ you are looking for.